# creating a grid of rectangles dynamically

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I wanted to create [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). I read the Java 2d API, but the Graphics class only provides methods to `drawRect()` and `fillRect()` on the paintComponent of a `JPanel`. I mean that the rectangles cannot be handled individually as objects i.e. so that i can check which one is on in relation to the ones in the vicinity.
So I wanted to ask how are squares to be made so that they can be handled individually and the grid be created dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Sqaure class with all properties required.
Create a list of Square objects representing the board.
In the draw method for the JPanel, iterate over your list of Square objects, drawing each one out, based on its properties.

Keep your display code separate from your logic as much as possible - it's nearly always a good idea.

Comment: How can i make the Square Selectable? can i implement the `MouseListener` Interface over the Square i made?

Comment: You can implement the MouseListener over the JPanel, get the co-ords of the click and check if those co-ords are inside any of your Square obejcts (I'd suggest either setting the co-ords of the Square object as you render them, or better yet, set the co-ords when creating the Squares, then use those co-ords to choose where to display them)

Comment: Good advice. For something like the Game of Life it would be much better to figure out the selected square(s) through  coordinate checks rather than trying to represent everything with components on a panel (like buttons or labels). It will be more responsive and light-weigth. Make sure to read up on the model-view-controller pattern, commonly abbreviated to MVC). Your grid is the model, the visualization is the view and at the same time the controller by responding to mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a completely different solution. Normally have to treat the generated graphics as output-only, meaning, you don't want to read state from the graphics because that'd be too slow.
You'll have to keep the state of the cells elsewhere, like in a two-dimensional array.
boolean[][] or int[][] for example.
Then you'll need a "render" method of sorts, that takes the values of your cells, and draws it out.

But I'd like to propose an even cooler way of doing this. Instead of keeping a two dimensional array, use the (one dimensional) array that a BufferedImage is made up of.
Normally, each "pixel" is an element in that array. Then you use drawImage to draw that image, and scale that image up. This could perform really well. You might be able to have an entire screen draw in real time pretty much.

There are various methods on BufferedImage, it gets a little confusing at first. In the end you'll find a DataBuffer somewhere. You'll want access to the int[].

Then, to set a cell: data[y * width + x] = -1; (white cell)
to clear a cell: data[y * width + x] = 0; (black cell)
(for example - or vice versa - or any other color).

You can get really fancy with this. You could use various offset variables instead of having to calculate the y*width+x all the time, and optimize it really well.
In fact, I go as far as being able to make it so efficient, that you could actually outperform another guy making the exact same program in C++.

Comment: If this is part of a performance contest, I can even propose an *even* more efficient algorithm. Way back when in the 80's, I used to use the Blitter chip in a Commodore Amiga, and created a Life program with that. I came up with a really weird algorithm that let me make a real time full screen high resolution game of life with it - and that was on a 7MHz computer (0.007 GHz). I could envision emulating a blitter and do this again. It's not something you'd normally think of, but it may well yield amazing results, like a 5000x5000 cell array at 100 fps or some ridiculous like that.

Comment: And then there is that GPU... could employ that as well. That goes beyond what I know.